# hash and unhash text to 20 characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, hash

I have some text from 3-100 characters,

I want to be able to hash it to a 20 chars string,

and be able to unhash it back to the original.

- security is not in mind, I just have a string limit, but I need the full string.

Comment: You cannot unhash. Hash maps data to a fixed size data. It is one way function. What you talk about sounds more like compression which is completely different thing.

Comment: It is not possible to arbitrary 100-character string into a 20-character string, and reverse it. Some information will be lost during hashing. Can you store a database mapping hashes to the original strings?

Comment: Well of course but I wanted to keep it without the db

Comment: I think what you mean is compressing, not hashing. Do you have a 20character or 20Byte limit? What encoding do you use? and what kind of text is it? does it mostly repeat? Basically is it compressible?

Comment: 20 characters, and basic string like: dogsPage2_fbPitbuls_onSidebar2

Comment: if your 3-100 character strings are limited to a small range of possible characters - let's say alphanumeric plus underscore - you can represent each character with 6 bits. JavaScript strings however offer 16 bit per character = 320 bits for a 20 character string. You can use these 320 bits to store up to 53 6-bit characters. If you want to store 100 characters, you would need to compress your strings to use an average 3.2 bits per character which might not always succeed.

Comment: This is a great question for people with limited experience with hashing or cryptography. It shouldn't be downvoted. Thanks everyone for their inputs. I had the same question

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible.

If you can to compress any 100-characters to 20 and back - you can to compress whole internet to 20 bytes :)

---

All you can - to limit original alphabet and use extended for hash.
For example, source string can be alphanumeric with case. It's 62 character alphabet. with hash used all 256 byte values you can compress source 4 times.

Comment: @TzookBarNoy Back in 1997 you could save the entire internet in a 3½ floppy but it isn't possible any more, it's become too large :-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, By `whole internet` I mean any sized data.